# Python output of thread running under systemd

Tags: python, multithreading, output, systemd

I currently have a python script which executes several other scripts as threads.

When the script is run directly in shell, I get the output in shell from print, of the main script, and all of the scripts being run as threads.

I have since moved the main script to run under systemd.

When I access journalctl -u script.service I only get print output of the main script and not the threads.

So the below prints to journalctl

```
print("[" + datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") + "][FLOW] Initialising Flow Sensors")

flow.initialiseTaps()
```

The prints included in the script below do not

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target = flow.monitorFlow)

t1.start()
```

The threads contain an infinite loop, that is working as it speaks to a remote API and it's doing everything it should, I'd just like to see the output the same as I do when I run the script directly in shell

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution and it was very simple.

The output was getting out from the threads, but the buffer would only release every hour. You can alter the buffer settings but I fixed it by changing

```
print("Hello")
```

to

```
print("Hello", flush=True)
```

I actually ended up creating a global function to format the output to simplify output but the key is adding the flush value to the print statement.

Cheers